# What does 'against' mean in the phrase 'Execute against a MySQL database'?

Tags: prepositions, technical, prepositional-phrases

I've encountered this strange and rather odd (to me) usage of the preposition 'against', which I quite can't grasp as of now. I've tried to look it up in several dictionaries to no avail.

Comment: One runs queries against (or upon) a set of data. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=upon+data%2Cagainst+data%2C+toward+data%2C+towards+data&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cupon%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cagainst%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoward%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctowards%20data%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Of interest: [Generate invoice “against” or “for” a sale order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395132/generate-invoice-against-or-for-a-sale-order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a ladder unless it is leaning **against** a wall or tree or some such object.

Likewise you can't use a SQL statement unless you have a database to run it **against**.

The database supports the SQL statement. The wall supports the ladder.

When I think of it like that *against* seems a natural choice.

Comment: You can compare usages like "[charged against her account](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/against)".

Answer (score 0):

It is a well used idiom in IT.

It is used as a synonym of ["towards"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/toward)

Have a look at some of the comments/answers here

[Against and Towards can be same?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40307/against-and-towards-can-be-same)

Comment: I'd not really think of it as a synonym for 'towards', even if such is technically correct - rather, I'd be likely to explain "execute <statement> against a MySQL database" as meaning that "the **operations in <statement> should be applied to the data in** the MySQL database".

Comment: I have heard both since I started in IT last millennium ;)

Comment: There are relatively few situations where *towards* and *against* are interchangeable, and I would say this is not one of them; in the last twenty years I have heard of things being executed *on*, *in*, *against*, and even *under* databases, but not *towards*. You can *point* some things toward a database, however.

Comment: Exactly: The word is used as something to point towards the database

Comment: **Towards** doesn't really work for me, either. SQL queries can be used to set up, define the structure of, create records in, retrieve data from, change records in, delete records from and drop tables from databases. They can even delete entire database instances. The term **against** covers all these but **towards** seems much weaker.

Comment: Towards as in “in direction of some external black box entity” “I direct my queries towards the cloud”

Answer (score 0):

The use of the preposition "against" in this context may be due to the fact that there is a specific type of query in SQL known as full-text search, which is typically performed using the syntax "MATCH ... AGAINST". Therefore, the use of "against" may be intended to emphasize that SQL is not only capable of performing regular queries, but also full-text search queries.

However, the use of "against" in this sentence is not strictly necessary, as other prepositions such as "from" could also be used to convey the same meaning.